# WSOD, time lag when creating/copying contribution, event pages

Tags: upgrade, wsod

We recently upgraded to WP 5.6, CiviCRM 5.32.1

Since the upgrade, we see this behavior:

1. When trying to create a new contribution or event page, we receive the White Screen of Death (WSOD) and nothing more
2. When copying an existing contribution or event page, we receive the WSOD, but shortly after returning to CiviCRM, a notification pops up that the copy was successful.  The copied item appears on the manage contribution or event page

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: You'll need to get the error from your webserver logs (e.g. apache, nginx, etc).

Comment: have you tried extra cache clearing?